# Sybase to Oracle - PowerBuilder Application Migration

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-conversion

We are planning to migrate Sybase to Oracle. The application is developed in PowerBuilder. 
Do we have any tool that finds the inline SQLs that are written in PowerBuilder Application? Also, please share some best practices that needs to be followed for the migration.

Please note that we are doing the Application migration not Database migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the inline SQL, look at Terry Voth's [PBL Peeper](http://www.techno-kitten.com/PBL_Peeper/pbl_peeper.html).

Comment: @Jiju: PBL Peeper will also help you dump the SQL from your DataWindows as well (Reports / DataWindow SQL) to help you identify functions or syntax used that may be incompatible. (@Slapout: Thanks for the mention!)